# How to insert value into MySQL table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table [user_id, name] that is prepopulated with a list of user_IDs. I want to create a form to allow a user to register a name against their user_id.

Here's the basic HTML form:

```
    <form action="" id="contact-form" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
          <label class="control-label" for="inputName">Enter Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control  input-lge" name="inputName" id="inputName">       
            <input type="hidden"  class="form-control" id="hidUid" name="hidUid" value="<?php echo $reg_user_id?>">
<input type="submit" id="sub_button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

Note the $reg_user_id is the user_id variable set by a session.

Here is my start at the PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['hidUid']) && isset($_POST['inputName'])){
  $inputName=$_POST['inputName'];
  $inputUid=$_POST['hidUid'];
  if ($stmtint = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT user_email FROM users WHERE user_ID=?")) {
   $stmtint->bind_param("s", $inputUid);
   $stmtint->execute();
   $stmtint->bind_result($user_email);
   $stmtint->fetch();
   $stmtint->close();
   if($user_email != "" && $inputName !=""){
    $user_email="";
    if ($stmtint = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET name=? where user_ID=?")) {
     $stmtint->bind_param("ss", $inputName,$inputUid);
     $stmtint->execute();
     $stmtint->close();        

      echo "User saved successfully";
      exit;
    }
  }
  else{
    echo "Please enter correct Name and password";
    exit;
  }

}
}
```

My problem is the form submits successfully, but the database doesn't update. I have no errors in either the PHP output or the console log. Any ideas?

Comment: You say "the form submits successfully"; have you checked the `POST` data? Also you don't check whether you query fails, so it will fail silently.

Comment: What value does the SELECT give you?  It doesn't seem as if it is used at all.  Why not just execute insert only.  You should add mysqli error handling you you can see if you are getting any mysqli errors.

Comment: @MikeBrant thanks, how do I add error handling?

Comment: Try echoing `mysql_error()`.

Comment: Just always check that the results of `mysqli->prepare()`, `->execute()`, etc. are returning values as expected.  If not look you can inspect `->error()` to see what went wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't pass your user ID out in the open like that. Someone could easily edit it. Try putting it into a session where the user can't fiddle with the value. And are you sure your user IDs are strings and not integers?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the error try this.

```
if(isset($_POST['hidUid']) && isset($_POST['inputName'])){

 $inputName = $_POST['inputName'];
 $inputUid = $_POST['hidUid'];

 if ($stmtint = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT user_email FROM users WHERE user_ID = ?")) {

   $stmtint->bind_param("s", $inputUid);

   if ($stmtint->execute()) {
     $stmtint->bind_result($user_email);
     $stmtint->fetch();
     $stmtint->close();
   }else{
     die("Error Message:".$mysqli->error);
   }

   if ($user_email != "" && $inputName != "") {

     $user_email="";

     if ($stmtint = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET name = ? where user_ID = ?")) {

       $stmtint->bind_param("ss", $inputName,$inputUid);

       if ($stmtint->execute()) {
         $stmtint->close();
         echo "User saved successfully";           
       }else{
         die("Error Message:".$mysqli->error);
       }

       exit;
     }

   }else{
   echo "Please enter correct Name and password";
   exit;
   }
 }
}
```